# FFmpeg: With 1 720p and 1 1080p video, how can I upscale the 1st one to 1080p and hstack them in one command?

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the command I have right now, but it only works for videos with the same height:

```
ffmpeg -i "video 1.mp4" -i "video 2.mp4" -c:a copy c:v h264_amf -filter_complex "hstack,format=yuv420p" "Output video.mp4"
```

- video 1.mp4 is the 720p one
- video 2.mp4 is the 1080p one

I need to keep the audio for the 1st video but not the 2nd one, the 2nd one doesn't have audio. I tried adding `[0:v]scale=-1:1080;` before `hstack` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there.

`ffmpeg -i "video 1.mp4" -i "video 2.mp4" -c:a copy c:v h264_amf -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:1080[v1];[v1][1:v]hstack,format=yuv420p" "Output video.mp4"`

If only the first video has audio, it will be automatically picked up by the above command.